# EF error when selecting: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. No SingleOrDefault, no Update

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have such an error due the following context:
I have 3 tables in database. User, Application, UserApplication. MyDbConext have this tables like a DbSet. UserApplication table have a FK to User table and FK to Application table.

```
public MyDbContext DbContext {get; set}
...........
public override IQueryable<User> Users
{
      get
      {
           var result = from user in DbContext.Users
                        where user.id == "some int variable"
                        select user;
                return result;
            }
        }
}
public override IQueryable<UserApplication> UserApplications
{
      get
      {
           var result = from app in DbContext.UserApplications
                        join user in Users on app .UserId equals user.Id
                        select app;
                return result;
      }
}
public override IQueryable<Application> Applications
{
      get
      {
           var result = from app in DbContext.Applications
                        join userApp in UserApplications 
                             on app.Id equals userApp.ApplicationId
                        select unsApp;
                return result;
       }
}
```

When I'm calling `Applications.ToList()` I have *Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object* exception. Also if i rewrite Applications to:

```
public override IQueryable<Application> Applications
{
      get
      {
           var result = from app in DbContext.Applications
                        join userApp in DbContext.UserApplications 
                             on app.Id equals userApp.ApplicationId
                        join user in Users on userApp.UserId equals user.Id
                        select unsApp;
                return result;
       }
}
```

everything works fine. Could anybody explain why exception happens?

Comment: shouldn't it be DbContext.Users in the `Applications` property? `join user in *DbContext.*Users on userApp.UserId equals user.Id`

Comment: No, I already have IQueryable<User> Users in which I have condition for User table. I don't want to write this conditions 2 times.

Comment: ahhh sorry... Gotacha ... I was confused by the coloring of SO...